# Spring Mongo convert to document from json string

Tags: spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I have a Mongo collection annotated with @Document and I want the possibility to also get that Java object from a String (JSON) as we're getting these classes pushed into a queue as String.

Is there a method in Spring-Data-Mongo which converts from JSON to the actual Document object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

and then

```
mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(MatchMongo.class, (DBObject) JSON.parse(json));
```

Thanks to freakman, your answer helped a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can try com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse() method. It returns object so you probably have to do the casting + it may be it need "class" field inside json string.

Comment: I get a BasicDbObject with the JSON.parse() method and the casting doesn't work... I posted the answer :) Thank you +1